# Is it okay to use "has been" here?

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect

My Dad (diabetic) and I went to a doctor for a checkup. The doctor advised my dad to increase his insulin because his sugar was high in those days. Furthermore doctor told my dad to call him after a week to let him know about his sugar.

It's day 3, but my dad's sugar has been low so far. Would the following sentence be fine for telling the doctor about his blood sugar?

> Its *has been* 3 days since you told me to increase his insulin but his sugar *has been* low, now what to do?

The main thing I want to know is the use of *has been*.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on English Language Learners.  http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

That usage is correct. It is right for (1) the passage of time, and (2) the existence of a condition during that period of time.

**Passage of Time** 3 days ago you were instructed to increase the insulin. "It has been X days since..." is the right way to tell how many days ago an event occurred. This construction puts the focus on the amount of time that has passed.

**Existence of a Condition** 'has been low' is correct, and can be interpreted at least two ways. The first way I understand this is to mean that his blood sugar was low multiple times. The second possible meaning is that there was a single time when your father's blood sugar was low. The 'has been' construction in this context focuses on the fact that it was low at all, which seems to be the most important for your father's health.